Convert Table Visual into new Table or Query Power Bi
Is there a way to convert a table visual into a query or new table measure? I'm still new to Power Bi
Table visual
Column and measure used

If I understand correctly , You would like to get the query executing behind a table visual where some columns & measures are used.
Copying the query running for visual is possible through performance analyser.

